# How to center table row items horizontally while keeping the corresponding table structure?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a row in a table while keeping the original table structure: so without adding td/tr divs. Is there a way to do this because I cannot find one.

So I want the last row items to be centered (Pr and Rs)

```css
.dna-table {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.dna-row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.dna-element {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
 }
 
.symbol {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="dna-table">
 
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Co</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Cn</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">En</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Ps</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Gr</p></td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Pr</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Rs</p></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Please add your CSS to the question as well. You can create a runnable snippet by clicking the "code document" icon in the editor and entering your code there (just like JSFiddle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By change the `<tr>` to `display: flex; justify-content: center` and adding some margin to your cells (to simulate the cell-spacing) you can probably get what you want.

```css
.dna-table {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.dna-row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; /*Add this*/
  justify-content: center; /*Add this*/
}

.dna-element {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px; /*Add this*/
 }
 
.symbol {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="dna-table">
 
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Co</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Cn</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">En</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Ps</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Gr</p></td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Pr</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Rs</p></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

**UPDATE**
If you can't use flexbox then try changing the rows `display` value to `block` and make the cells `display: inline-block;`, then set `text-align:center;` on the row. See below:

```css
.dna-table {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.dna-row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block; /*Add this*/
  text-align: center; /*Add this*/
}

.dna-element {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block; /*Add this*/
  margin: 1px; /*Add this*/
 }
 
.symbol {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="dna-table">
 
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Co</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Cn</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">En</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Ps</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Gr</p></td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="dna-row">
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Pr</p></td>
      <td class="dna-element"><p class="symbol">Rs</p></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to avoid `flexbox`? I did not mention it, but the target browser is a browser which does not support flexbox unfortunatelly.